# Pandas. How to improve performance. Iterating is too slow

Tags: pandas, iteration

I have a dataset like

| id | open_month | end_month | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2023-01-31 | 2023-02-28 | 1 |
| 002 | 2023-01-31 | 2023-03-31 | 5 |
| 003 | 2023-01-31 | 2023-04-30 | 4 |
| 004 | 2023-02-28 | 2023-02-28 | 2 |
| 005 | 2023-02-28 | 2023-03-31 | 3 |
| 006 | 2023-02-28 | 2023-04-30 | 6 |
| 007 | 2023-03-31 | 2023-03-31 | 7 |
| 008 | 2023-03-31 | 2023-04-30 | 9 |

```
x = pd.DataFrame({
  'id': ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008'],
  'open_month': ['2023-01-31', '2023-01-31', '2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-02-28', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-03-31'],
  'end_month': ['2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30'],
  'quantity': [1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9]
}
)
```

I need to get a table where rows are the number of months since opening from 0, columns are the months of opening, values are quantity of ended items.

Desired result

|  | 2023-01-31 | 2023-02-28 | 2023-03-31 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 16 |
| 2 | 6 | 11 | 16 |

```
table = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(x['open_month'].unique())):
    for month in x['open_month'].unique():
        date = month + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(i)
        table.at[i, month] = x.query('open_month == @month and end_month <= @date')['quantity'].sum()
```

My code works as I expected, but too slow on real data (> 2 mln ID's)

Answer (score 1):

Try to build a DataFrame basing on list comprehension:

```
open_months = x['open_month'].unique()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[x[x['open_month'].eq(m) 
                               & x['end_month'].le(m + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(i))]['quantity'].sum() 
                             for i in range(len(open_months))]
                             for m in open_months]).T, columns=open_months)
```

---

```
   2023-01-31  2023-02-28  2023-03-31
0           0           2           7
1           1           5          16
2           6          11          16
```

Comment: Thanks. It's more than five times faster. 1 min vs 5.5 min.